# Threading MVC 6 .net 5

Tags: c#, .net, api, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

Hey guys I have developed an API where I am handling requests that redirect to multiple databases.

It has been working fine, but have recently hit a road block. I have been googling for two days and trying several different solution but they all do not seem to work.

My application is handling requests on a FIFO basis.

```
    [HttpGet("getList")]
    public string Get(string token, string page, string amount) {
        string value = null;
        var thread = new Thread(
          () => {
              value = CustomerDA.getList(token, page, amount);
        });
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
        return value;
    }
```

This is the most up to date solution that I have tried... I need to return a string back to client based on what they pass into this method call. I am confused because I thought that this technology handled these requests asynchronously by default.

Here is another attempt:

```
    [HttpGet("getList")]
    public async Task<string> Get(string token, string page, string amount) {
        var t = Task<int>.Run(() => {
            return CustomerDA.getList(token, page, amount);
        });
        return t.Result;
    }
```

Thanks You!

Comment: Why are you starting a thread and then immediately waiting for it to finish?

Comment: Ultimately I want to start the thread an then go onto handling other requests... How would I return a value to the client without waiting for it to finish essentially?

Comment: You want async, not threading.  That's only possible if you have an async API to call.  Read http://blog.slaks.net/2014-12-23/parallelism-async-threading-explained/

Comment: I have tried using Async Tasks but was still not successful. I have been looking for example code but everything looks to be outdated at this point.

Comment: public async Task<actionresult> Index()
        {
            return View(await db.Employees.ToListAsync());
        }


I tried something similar to this but was unable to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second attempt you create a `Task` (= Thread) and then immediately wait synchronously for it to finish. If you want to wait asynchronously, you have to use `await`.

```
[HttpGet("getList")]
public async Task<string> Get(string token, string page, string amount) {
    var t = Task<int>.Run(() => {
        return CustomerDA.getList(token, page, amount);
    });
    return await t;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, its exactly the same solution you found. Just the await is in another place.

Comment: Please accept your answer or mine (whichever you like better), so people dont think you havent got the solution ;)

Comment: Sorry about that got too excited. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the issue thanks to SLaks and him pointing me in the right direction:

```
    [HttpGet("getList")]
    public async Task<string> Get(string token, string page, string amount) {
        var t = await Task.Run(() => {
            return CustomerDA.getList(token, page, amount);
        });
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: Don't do this; it will just make your problems worse.  Unless you actually have a non-blocking method to call, async will not help you.

Comment: It is simply calling a SQL query which is going to return data. What would you suggest?